# Let matrix $A$ be normal. If $A{A^T}$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, why is $A$ symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let matrix $A \in {M_n}(\Bbb R)$ be normal. If $A{A^T}$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, why is $A$ symmetric?

Comment: **Hint:** if $A$ is normal, then for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, $|\lambda|^2$ is an eigenvalue of $AA^T$.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a late answer.

First, a bit of notation. Since we will work over $\mathbb C,$ we will need the notion of "conjugate-transpose" of a complex matrix. Namely, if $M\in \mathbb C^{n\times n},$ then its "conjugate-transpose" is defined as
$$
M^H = (\overline M)^T,
$$
where $\overline \cdot$ denotes complex conjugation of the matrix entries and $\cdot^T$ denotes matrix transposition. This is a well known operation. Observe that $\overline \cdot$ and $\cdot^T$ commute. And, of course, for $N\in\mathbb R^{n\times n},$ we have $N^H = N^T.$ In the following, we will use only the operation $\cdot^H.$

On to the actual question. So we are given a matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ which is normal, i.e. $A^HA = AA^H$ and such that $A^HA$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues. We want to show that $A$ is symmetric, i.e. $A^H = A.$

Observe that, since $A$ is real, its characteristic polynomial has real coefficients. This means that the eigenvalues of $A,$ i.e. the roots of its characteristic polynomial, are either real or come in complex conjugate pairs. In other words, we can enumerate the eigenvalues of $A$ as a sequence
$$
\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_r,\mu_1,\overline{\mu_1},\ldots,\mu_s,\overline{\mu_s},
$$
with $r,s\in \mathbb N_0,$ $\lambda_j\in\mathbb R,$ and $\mu_k\in \mathbb C$ with $\Im\mu_k > 0.$ Repetitions are allowed, i.e. we can have $\lambda_j = \lambda_k$ or $\mu_j = \mu_k$ for $j\neq k.$

Now, since $A$ is normal, it can be diagonalized using a unitary transformation. This is a [well known fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix). In more detail, we have the following. Put
$$
D = {\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_r,\mu_1,\overline{\mu_1},\ldots,\mu_s,\overline{\mu_s})\in \mathbb C^{n\times n},
$$
i.e. $D$ is the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$ on the diagonal. Then, there is a unitary matrix $U\in \mathbb C^{n\times n}$ such that
$$
\tag{1}
A = U^HDU.
$$
Recall that "unitary" means
$$
\tag{2}
U^HU = UU^H = I,
$$
where $I \in \mathbb C^{n\times n}$ is the identity matrix. From $(1),$ we get
$$
\tag{3}
A^H = (U^HDU)^H = U^HD^HU.
$$
From $(1),$ $(2),$ and $(3),$ we conclude
$$
A^HA = \left(U^HD^HU\right)\left(U^HDU\right) = U^HD^HDU.
$$
This shows that the eigenvalues of $A^HA$ are the diagonal elements of the dialgonal matrix
$$
\begin{align}
D^HD & = {\rm diag}(\lambda_1^2,\ldots,\lambda_r^2,\overline{\mu_1}\mu_1,\mu_1\overline{\mu_1},\ldots,\overline{\mu_s}\mu_s,\mu_s\overline{\mu_s}) \\
& = {\rm diag}(\lambda_1^2,\ldots,\lambda_r^2,|\mu_1|^2,|\mu_1|^2,\ldots,|\mu_s|^2,|\mu_s|^2).
\end{align}
$$
Observe that every pair $\mu_j,\overline{\mu_j}$ of complex conjugate eigenvalues of $A$ produces twice the same eigenvalue for $A^HA.$ By assumption, this can't happen. So we must have that $s = 0,$ $A$ has only real eigenvalues, and in particular $D\in \mathbb R^{n\times n},$ i.e. $D$ is real. But then
$$
\tag{4}
D^H = D.
$$
Now we get from $(1),$ $(3),$ and $(4)$
$$
A^H = U^HD^HU = U^HDU = A,
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Since $AA^T$ is symmetric ($(AA^T)^T=AA^T$), $AA^T$ has an orthonormal eigenvector base. Since $AA^T$ has $n$ distinict eigenvalues, each eigenvalue only has one eigenvector.

Suppose $P=[u_1,\cdots,u_n] \hspace{2 mm} (u_i$  is the eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $AA^T$). Then
$$
P^{-1}(AA^T)P=P^{T}(AA^T)P=\operatorname{diag}[\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n]
$$

Since $A$ is normal
$$
A \hspace{2 mm}\text{and}\hspace{2 mm} AA^T \hspace{2 mm} \text{are commute, for}\hspace{2 mm} A(AA^T)=A(A^TA)=(AA^T)A
$$
Since
$$
A(AA^T)u_i=(AA^T)(Au_i)=A(\lambda_iu_i)=\lambda_i(Au_i)
$$
If $Au_i\neq0$, $Au_i$ is an eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $AA^T$. Since there is only one such eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, $Au_i=\mu_i u_i,\space \mu_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Thus $P$ is also an orthonormal eigenvector base for $A$. So there is
$$P^{T}AP=\operatorname{diag}[\mu_1,\cdots,\mu_n] \hspace{2 mm} \text{and}\hspace{2 mm} A=P\operatorname{diag}[\mu_1,\cdots,\mu_n]P^T
$$

$A$ is symmetric for
$$A^T=(P\operatorname{diag}[\mu_1,\cdots,\mu_n]P^T)^T=P\operatorname{diag}[\mu_1,\cdots,\mu_n]P^T=A
$$

Comment: Very nice. I don't expect that there is such a perspective.

Comment: @hermes, How do you know that $Au_i\neq0$. If $Au_i=0$ then it can not be an eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. How to be sure that $Au_i\neq0$???

Comment: OK. But how you know that $A^TAu_i\neq0$??

Comment: What do you mean by trivial eigenvector? Is it zero vector? But an eigenvector is always  nonzero.....see in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#:~:text=In%20linear%20algebra%2C%20an%20eigenvector,which%20the%20eigenvector%20is%20scaled.

Comment: What is $\mu_i$ here?? and what do you mean by the eigenvector of 0 is 0??

Comment: $\mu_i$ are eigenvalues of $A$. Read the post again. If $Au_i=\mu_i u_i$ and $\mu_i=0$, then $u_i=0$. Otherwise $Au_i\neq\mu_i u_i$

Comment: But how you can conclude that $Au_i=\mu_iu_i$ and $\mu_i=0$ then $u_i=0$?? $A$ may be a singular matrix, not necessarily invertible. In that case how you can conclude that  $u_i=0$?????

Comment: Yes, the eigenvector of $0$ may not be $0$. So there is no need for $u_i=0$. It is enough though. If $Au_i=0$,  $u_i$ is the eigenvector of $0$

Comment: What do you mean by   " If $Au_i=0$, $u_i$ is the eigenvector of $0$"  ?

Comment: Read the post again. $Au_i=μ_iu_i=0$ means $μ_i=0$. So $u_i$ is the eigenvector of $0$

Comment: but in that case $Au_i$ is zero vector and then how we can write it as a scalar multiple of  $u_i$. Basically I want to say $Au_i$ can not be zero at any case as it was assumed to be an eigenvector or we need to show that $Au_i$ is never zero.

Comment: I really run out of patience on this. $Au_i$ can be zero while $u_i$ is not. So your thinking is wrong

Comment: But in the post you have written $Au_i$ is an eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. Then how  $Au_i$ can be zero? Because an eigenvector can not be a zero vector (by definition, an eigenvector is always a non zero vector)

Comment: I modified it. If $Au_i=0$, it is reduced to a degenerated case.

Comment: ok.Can you do the proof for $Au_i=0$??

Comment: It is already in previous comments. $Au_i=μ_iu_i=0$ means $μ_i=0$. So $u_i$ is the eigenvector of $0$ which is also an eigenvalue fo $AA^T$

Comment: If $Au_i=0$, can you write $Au_i$ as a linear combination of  $u_i$?

Comment: No, no need to do that. $Au_i=0$ means $u_i$ is the eigenvector of $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $X\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ being normal is equivalent to the existence of a unitary matrix $U\in \mathrm U(n)\subset \mathbb C^{n\times n}$ such that $U^* X U=D\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ is a complex diagonal matrix. It is symmetric if and only if all eigenvalues of $X$ (the diagonal entries of $D$) are real numbers.

Hence,
$$
X^T X = UD^* U^* UDU^* = U D^* D U^*
$$
and the matrix $X^T X$ is similar to $D^* D$.

Assume that $X$ is not symmetric for sake of contradiction, then $X$ has at least one pair of complex eigenvalues $\lambda=a\pm b\mathrm i$ with $b\neq 0$. But then $D^* D$ has the repeated diagonal entry
$$
(a-b\mathrm i)(a+b\mathrm i) = a^2 + b^2 = (a+b\mathrm i)(a-b\mathrm i),
$$
which can't be the case since $X^T X$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues by assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Since $AA^T$ is a symmetric matrix, it has an orthogonal eigenbasis.

Be $v$ an eigenvector of $AA^T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then we have
$$(AA^T)(Av) = A(A^TA)v = A(AA^T)v = A\lambda v = \lambda Av$$
where in the second step I used the normality of $A$.

But since $AA^T$ has $n$ different eigenvalues, each of its eigenspaces has dimension $1$, therefore the above equation implies that $v$ and $Av$ have to be linear dependent, and since $v$ is non-zero, this means there exists a $\mu$ such that $Av=\mu v$. But that equation means that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Thus $A$ has an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors (namely the same one as $AA^T$). But a matrix that has an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors is symmetric.

Comment: This is basically what is in my answer. Why do you post it again?

Comment: Your answer says much more (including a reference to another post and a claim that is not actually true — $A$ can have negative eigenvalues, after all). I think having a concise post that says no more than necessary is valuable. YMMV.

Comment: The reference to another post is not needed and is removed. (I added the link because a lady concerned about a part of the proof but is resolved.) In this situation, you should say in the post something like "based on other post".

Comment: @hermes: But it wasn't based on your post. Indeed, if you look carefully, I did some things slightly different than your post. But more importantly, I didn't study your post before writing mine; I just took a glance, saw a lot of details, and decided it was needlessly complicated. Then I independently wrote my post.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=USV^T$ be a singular value decomposition. Then $US^2U^T=AA^T=A^TA=VS^2V^T$. Hence $S^2$ commutes with $V^TU$. However, as all eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are distinct, $S^2$ has distinct diagonal entries. Therefore $V^TU$ is a diagonal matrix. Let $V^TU=D$. Then $A=USV^T=V(DS)V^T$ is symmetric.

Answer (score -4):

$A$ is normal and $AA^T$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, so $AA^T=X \Lambda^2X^{-1}=A^TA $, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal and has $\lambda$'s on the diagonal.

Now $AA^T=(X \Lambda X^{-1})(X \Lambda X^{-1})=A^TA $ so that $A=A^T$.

Comment: $A$ normal means that $AA^T=A^TA$. But $AA^T=A^TA$ does not imply $A=A^T$ in general.